# Data sync from different SQL Server versions databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, synchronization, sql-server-7

So I have an SQL Server 7.0 database that must not be upgraded, it only gets data read and written in it, and I created an SQL Server 2008 R2 database which is the same structure, I want to synchronize the data between both, so whatever addition, deletion or modification happens on the SS7.0 happens in the SS2008 R2, and vice versa, is there a way to do so? I'm not asking for a ready answer, I just want a trail to follow, tips and such, so far I only managed to export a copy of the data with bcp, but I can't do it each time
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's almost 20 years old. Wouldn't it be a good idea to upgrade it?

Comment: the thing is my boss doesn't want to upgrade it, it will cost dearly and cause troubles for other workers, I spoke to him about upgrade but he said it's a no go

Comment: Well, it's probably not going to be simple to build a 2 way replication either, since what do you do if there's conflicts in the data? You probably could do this with SSIS, but it's not a simple thing -- and depends a lot on the number of tables of course.